# Javascript eval causes Syntax error on IIS

Tags: asp-classic, eval, serverside-javascript

I am trying to use javascript code in server side to parse JSON input into object. Beause there is no native support for JSON deserialization in classic asp, I have tried to use Douglas Crockford's javascript library https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js included as server side code.

I have used this solution on IIS Express without problem, but when I moved my code on regular IIS I have experienced this error:

```
Microsoft JScript compilation error '800a03ea'

Syntax error
```

and this line was the culprit `j = eval('(' + text + ')');`.

So I started to fool it with something like:

```
text = '(' + text + ')';
j = eval(text);
```

but line with eval always caused error. After no success I have tried to simplify the code to eliminate any possible interference and come to this simple code which still causes error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/jscript" language="jscript" runat="server">
            function Test(text) {
                eval('(' + text + ')');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><% Test("Test") %></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is, does anybody have a clue what can cause regular IIS to dislike this use of eval?

Comment: eval is evil.. use it as less as possible.

Comment: @bitsMix, in general yes, but here is from the source code what Dough does to sanitize the eval expression: *First we replace the JSON backslash pairs with '@' (a non-JSON character). Second, we
replace all simple value tokens with ']' characters. Third, we delete all
open brackets that follow a colon or comma or that begin the text. Finally,
 we look to see that the remaining characters are only whitespace or ']' or
 ',' or ':' or '{' or '}'. If that is so, then the text is safe for eval.*

Comment: @stivlo - when you look at the last code you'll see simple (yet faulty) use with specific input. Full code have received valid JSON and as I have stated it worked on IIS Express.

Comment: What is the contents of `text`? Why do you add brackets? The result is simply not valid format.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: the parentheses are from the original code in `json2.js`.  The source comment says: _The '{'_ (that's a curly brace) _operator is subject to a syntactic ambiguity in JavaScript: it can begin a block or an object literal. We wrap the text in parens to eliminate the ambiguity._

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the value of `text` but the final string you try to evaluate is not in valid format. Maybe because of the brackets you add.

Anyhow, to make your test work first change the function to:

```
function Test(text) {
    return eval(text);
}
```

Then pass to it something that can be evaluated:

```
<p><%= Test("1+1") %></p>
```

Worked fine for me.

Comment: At first I have tried to eval "1 + 1" text too. Worked flawlessly. The problem are those parentheses. This produces syntax error:

Comment: No it's not. It's your actual data. I have changed the test case to `<%= Test("({ 'first': 'value' })['first']") %>` and it worked fine, printing "value" - like I asked, post the full contents of your `text` and we'll see why it's not valid JSON.